# How can i load a VSPackage with a PLK

Tags: visual-studio-2008, load, package, vspackage

Hi all i create a VsPackage that i wan't to deploy. In the experimental hive everything works fine, but when i try to use the PLK obtained in this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc655795 i receive an error message in the load process. I follow step by step the instructions to add the PLK from this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb165968(v=VS.90).aspx, so i don't know what is the problem. Has someone an alternative procedure or maybe a missing step from the instructions that is producing this failure in the load process?

pd: the error message doesn't say anything useful.."Tha package... load has fail, contact the vendor.."

I'm using Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check that the problem is really caused by the PLK. You can do this by running Visual Studio with /log option (i.e. [VisualStudioPath]\Common7\IDE\devenv /log) and then checking created log file in 
*C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Visual Studio\9.0\ActivityLog.xml* . Generally, this error can be caused by any exception thrown in your Initialize() method.

If the problem is really in PLK, make sure you are not using any "weird" characters in either your package's name or you company's name. 
Do not use special characters (,.!? ...) and diacritics (ěščřžýáíü ...).
Make sure you are using correct edition of Visual Studio (NOT Express Edition).
Check if your PLK is correctly included in ResX file - particularly if there are no line breaks in ResX element containing your PLK.
Try changing your package's GUID and generate new PLK to it.

Hope it helps, I had pretty hard time running VSPackage myself :-)